# What type of memory is this?

Tags: memory, ddr3

The laptop only takes 1 stick of memory.  I don't know the specifics of this memory beyond DDR3 1333.  Is it with parity, without parity?  What else do I need to know to buy a replacement?  Unfortunately, the laptop is a no-name brand, and I can't just look up the specs. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: What's the manufacturer/model of the laptop?

Comment: Is that the ram came with the laptop?

Comment: Can you find the CPU? If you can find the CPU model it you can find its memory type. If its windows 7 or later try using going to 'my computer' and clicking properties, it should say there. You should only need to know the memory type, DDR3 sounds like what you need, they're pretty much all the same, their differences won't damage your PC

Comment: I think I found it. Go to this [link](http://www.gloway.com/product-43.html?do=info) and then go to the **Product Specifications** tab. Yes, I know the ram has a black PCB but I am 90% sure that this is it. It just might be a newer version of the ram that you showed [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KUj5P.jpg).

Comment: If you can't tell us anything about the laptop itself we cannot help you identify anything about the memory your asking about.

Comment: You could punch in DDR3 1333 into Amazon search bar, and it will give you all you need. You'd also need to know pin count. This one seems like 204 pins, but I am no expert

Answer (score 0):

This is a SO-DIMM DDR3 RAM with 1.8 Volts. So you have to look for [SO-DIMM DDR3 RAM which also has 1.8 Volts and has a speed of 1333MHz](http://geizhals.eu/takems-so-dimm-1gb-tms1gs364d081-139ke-a695419.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have everything that you need to know:

- DDR3
- 1333 MHz
- 1 GB

All you have to do now, is to get a SODIMM with the same specs (1GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz)